# PHP: Using quote() on strings in MDB2 with MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, quoting, mdb2

I'm using Pear's MDB2 and really enjoying it, but there is something that is starting to annoy me. I build the SQL string in the following way, using the quote method of the mdb2 package:

```
$sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO profiles(email, fullName) VALUES(%s,%s)", 
                     $mdb2->quote($email), $mdb2->quote($fullName));
```

(as explained in the example on this page: http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.database.mdb2.intro-quote.php)

and everything looks nice in the database. But when I extract data from the database, still using MDB2 I can't seem to find an easy way of stripping the quoting added by the quote method. At the moment I am using the stripslashes, but this doesn't seem right. Am I missing a setting somewhere? I am I using the package in the wrong way?

Thank you for you help,
Leif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that turning off [`magic_quotes_gpc`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc), and [`magic_quotes_runtime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-runtime), to be the best approach. In fact, as of `5.3.0` these directives have been deprecated. In `6.0` they have been removed all together.